# {"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid","status":401,"timestamp":1524402208502}

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, spinnaker

I am trying to integrate my spinnaker application with Okta. I created application in Okta.

Spinnaker Dashboard Application configuration:

[image]

I have configured my gate-local.yml file accordingly.

saml:

```
 enabled: true
 metadataUrl: file:/opt/spinnaker/config/metadata.xml
 keyStore: file:/opt/spinnaker/config/saml.jks
 keyStorePassword: <password>
 keyStoreAliasName: saml
 issuerId: <issuerId>
```

When I hit url `http://localhost:8084` i am getting redirect to Okta login page. Once I successfully logged in I am getting error message as

> {"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid","status":401,"timestamp":1524402208502}

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This is SAML flow. You are likely hitting step 4 and not passing it.

You should use [SAML Tracer](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SAML/saml_tracer) to check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think most likely SAML is failing at step 7. I am getting a response from SAML, but failing an assertion. I used SAMl tracer as you suggested and monitored SAML Request and Response. I think the SAML Response I am getting is rather correct. But still don't know which fields I should check, to know where it failing an assertion.Could you please help me with this. I am struggling with this for quite some time. Thanks in advance....

Comment: If you need some server logs, i can provide those also

Comment: You need to use the SAML Tracer I linked and check where it is failing